# Failed to create a symbolic link

Tags: apt, compiling, acer

```
akhil@akhil-Aspire-E1-571:~$ sudo apt-get install gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi 
[sudo] password for akhil: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gcc-arm-linux-gnueabi is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
akhil@akhil-Aspire-E1-571:~$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc’: No such file or directory
akhil@akhil-Aspire-E1-571:~$ cd zee-bow/u-boot-Digilent-Dev/
akhil@akhil-Aspire-E1-571:~/zee-bow/u-boot-Digilent-Dev$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc’: No such file or directory
akhil@akhil-Aspire-E1-571:~/zee-bow/u-boot-Digilent-Dev$ sudo ln -s /home/SDK/2014.4/gnu/arm/lin/arm-xilinx-linux-gnueabi-gcc usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc’: No such file or directory
akhil@akhil-Aspire-E1-571:~/zee-bow/u-boot-Digilent-Dev$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a `/` missing in `usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc`. Use

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc /usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc
```

Comment: Still there is some error which is not allowing me to go further
akhil@akhil-Aspire-E1-571:~/zee-bow/u-boot-Digilent-Dev$ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc /usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc
[sudo] password for akhil: 
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc’: File exists
akhil@akhil-Aspire-E1-571:~/zee-bow/u-boot-Digilent-Dev$

Comment: @Akhil Chandra Maganti your symbolic link already exits there .

Answer (score 2):

use command

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc /usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc
```

EDIT:
as you comment you are getting error :

```
ln: failed to create symbolic link ‘/usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc’: File exists
```

it means there is already symbolic link exist with  name `arm-linux-gcc` . either keep another name if you don't have problem with name or if you created this no problem your symbolic link created successfully  or you want to sure then delete symbolic name using below command and recreate it .

```
unlink /usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc /usr/bin/arm-linux-gcc
```